# Browser Widget slows QGIS

Tags: qgis-3

I read a lot of speeding up the browser widget, but nothing seemed to help me.

As long i have it closed QGIS 3 is fast but if I open it all actions slows down.

My project is on a local ssd - fast dir scan is enabled on all devices.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by opening the Browse Widget, right clicking on drives I don't need to access and clicking "hide from browser". In my case that included the C: D: (DVD drive), and Y: (my recovery drive sector), leaving everything else as is.
Because of the lengthy delay problem, it will take a bit of time. Once all the unneeded drives were hidden, the browser didn't bog anything down.
Sorry I don't have an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: I did nearly the same and filtered by using the filter button to the project name ('s geopackage) and it will work fast(er). I see now - I updated to 3.8.3 and didn't looked there again that all drives are twice in the browser list (browser, and browser 2). I do not know why there are to browser widgets)

Comment: Works for me as well. Thanks. How would I "unhide" a directory?

Comment: Go to Settings->Options->Data Sources. At the bottom you'll see "Hidden Browser Paths". Just select the path you want to unhide and hit the red delete button.