# QGIS Slow to respond, still remains

Tags: qgis, gui

I have the same problem that I have already complained about in the past.
Version 3.34.3 Prizren,
without any layers, with all plugins deactivated, new profile.
But there's nothing to be done, as soon as QGIS is launched it falls asleep with the hourglass spinning, then it wakes up working well but then every now and then it goes back to sleep again. Sometimes he is at the limit of usability.

Still no suggestions for a solution to the problem?

Comment: Lots of similar question have answer that point the QGIS browser as source of the problem and advise to close the browser panel if open and to hide any unnecessary (or unreachable) drive from it (for exemple :  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336036/qgis-3-browser-widget-slows-qgis)

Comment: probably because you have a saved connection to something that is very slow to access and Qgis load it when started

Comment: Oh yeaaah, I had a B: drive connected to the NAS which is usually turned off. Hide that connection and the problem seems to be gone. Guys thank you very much! I love you !